# All Values replaced by last value in For loop TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a for loop in javascript which concats data in **calendarEvents**:

```
drop(info) {
    var that = this;
    var startDate = info.date;
    var frequency = this.skippingNumber;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      (function (start) {
        that.calendarEvents = that.calendarEvents.concat({
          title: 'Dropped Event',
          start: start,
          allDay: info.allDay
        });
      })(startDate);
      startDate = this.addDays(startDate, frequency);
    }
  }

addDays(date: Date, days: number): Date {
    var passedDate = date;
    passedDate.setDate(passedDate.getDate() + days);
    return passedDate;
  }
```

If I log **startDate** inside the loop , I get actual values i.e, **Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday**. But when I log **calendarEvents**, all I get is Thursday in every data. 
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Your `startDate` is the same object and you're passing a reference to it every time.

Comment: All invocations of `addDays()` receive as argument, modify and return the same object (`var startDate = info.date`).

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/a50jte/is_it_best_to_use_var_or_let_in_for_loop/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All invocations of `addDays()` receive as argument, modify and return the same object (`var startDate = info.date`).

Rewrite the `addDays()` method to create and return a new `Date` object:

```
addDays(date: Date, days: number): Date {
    var passedDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    passedDate.setDate(passedDate.getDate() + days);
    return passedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have one `startdate` object that you're mutating as the loop runs. When it finishes, you have an array that contains references to the same object.

One fix would be to clone your startdate object before you concat it into the array:

```
(function (start) {
    that.calendarEvents = that.calendarEvents.concat({
      title: 'Dropped Event',
      start: new Date(start.getTime()),
      allDay: info.allDay
    });
  })(startDate);
```

Though as suggested it would be better to re-write your `addDays` function so that it doesn't mutate the date object you pass in. Where possible, functions should not mutate their inputs.